# Returning multiple errors in console 30 seconds after form submit

Tags: javascript

To summarize, the results of my form are based on a URL that is submitted, and when the form is submitted, I am fetching data from my express backend.

When I search a url, nothing seems to happen in my console. Then, after about 30 seconds I receive the console errors of

```
GET https://localhost.com/lookup/url net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

pointing to the lines of   `const response = await fetch(url, {` and   `getData ('https://localhost.com/lookup/url')` and the error of:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous)
```

pointing to the line of   `.then(data => {`

culminating in `fetch failed loading: GET "https://localhost.com/lookup/url"`

The full block of code is below:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); getData(); })

async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {
    
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    return response.json();
  }

  getData ('https://localhost.com/lookup/url')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Any insight as to what I would be doing wrong and an answer as to how this could be resolved in order to return json from my backend would be appreciated. Still learning, so apologies for all the errors at once.

---

Re: comment about port #, this is how I have my port setup

````
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
    ```
Using the // in the url will comment out the rest
````

Comment: Are you sure localhost.com is a website? Make sure the server you are hosting is correctly linked

Comment: You probably want `http://localhost:3000`, replacing the `3000` with whatever port your Express server is listening on.

Comment: @ZacAnger updated original post

Comment: @DaMahdi03 My app.get in the backend is ```app.get('/lookup/:url'``` so should it just be lookup/url in the front end?

Comment: If your express server is also serving your frontend (with express.static or using templates with res.render), on the same port, then yeah, you can leave out the scheme, domain, and port entirely. If your frontend is on a different port, you'll need to leave those in

Answer (score 1):

`fetch("https://localhost.com/location/url")` seems a bit strange for two reasons:

1. the name of the local machine typically is `localhost` and not `localhost.com` and
2. you probably don't have a certificate for your local testserver, so you can't use a `https` connection.

And because you have the wrong domain, `fetch()` cannot establish a connection to `https://localhost.com/location/url`. So after the default timeout of 30 seconds, it throws an error.

If, by any chance, the domainname `localhost.com` is correct (maybe it's just a disguise for the real domainname here in the post), you are probably missing the port. Because `https://localhost.com` will per default try to connect to port `443`.

So you probably want just

```
getData("http://localhost:port/lookup/url")
```

or if your server hosting both, the your frontend files and the api, you can simply do

```
getData("/lookup/url")
```